# Phone Blocked: Activate Wifi on Android from adb (not rooted phone)

Tags: android

How can i activate WiFi using ADB. In fact my phone is blocked after accidental retries to unlock using schema. The problem the phone is blocked and asks me to login into my gmail account.

I cannot do this because the WiFi is desactivated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not enable wifi but you could disable the lock screen itself

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

Edit: Do this in OnCreate itself. Since Eclipse automatically launches the app it will get run. Above method works for password lock screen, havent tried with forgot password screen